# Javascript XML HierarchyRequestError

Tags: javascript, xml

```
var xmlRoot = "<root></root>";
var firstChildNode = "<firstChild></firstChild>";

var parser = new DOMParser();
var xmlDom = parse.parseFromString(xmlRoot, "text/xml");
var xmlChildNode = parse.parseFromString(firstChildNode, "text/xml");

xmlDom.appendChild(xmlChildNode);
```

So above is what I was trying to test. I do not understand why I am getting a HierarchyRequestError. Can someone point out to me where my logic is flawed? It seems I am not understanding the concept properly.

Answer (score 0):

So I managed to make it work with the following:

```
xmlDom.firstChild.appendChild(xmlChildNode.firstChild);
```

as for some reason `xmlDom.firstChild` returns `<root></root>`. In this case, what is xmlDom then? I feel like there's a concept I'm not understanding properly...